# The best pythonic way to clean a string

Tags: python, string, data-cleaning

I've got a string like:

```
                            inconnue
                (1h 30min)
```

I'm looking for the best pythonic way (elegant way) to extract those 2 strings `inconnue` and `1h 30min` from a string full of space and break lines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string.splitlines()` will give you a list of the lines, and then to remove the whitespace, you can use `.strip()`.  For example: `stripped_list = map(str.strip, unstripped_list)`.  You can merge the two with `lines = map(str.strip, string.splitlines())`

Answer (score 2):

Use `strip` and `splitlines`:

```
>>> lines = "                            inconnue\n                (1h 30min)"
>>> [s.strip() for s in lines.splitlines()]
```

will result in

```
['inconnue', '(1h 30min)']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.splitlines()` and `str.strip()` in a list comprehension:

```
>>> string = """                            inconnue
...                 (1h 30min)"""
>>> [s.strip() for s in string.splitlines()]
['inconnue', '(1h 30min)']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
map(str.strip,a.strip().split(" ",1))
```

It returns the array below that you can parse further assuming you want to determine the duration of the unknown(`inconnue`) status

```
['inconnue', '(1h 30 min)']
```